# Trigger a workflow of another repository and get the artifacts

Tags: github, github-actions, github-ci

I have a private GitHub repository named "Test Repo" under an organization. The repository has an action that performs a workflow and uploads an artifact (HTML). I have ten more private repositories named "Dev Repos" under the same organization.

Is there a way where the below steps could happen whenever there is a push in any of the "Dev Repos"?

- Trigger the "Test Repo" workflow. The "Dev Repos" should show a processing workflow status.
- Once the "Test Repo" workflow is complete, the artifact of the "Test Repo" should appear in the "Dev Repos" where the push was made.

**Note**: It'll be nice to use native approaches rather than 3rd party plugins :)

---

**EDIT I**

Below is the native approach to trigger the workflow of the "Test Repo" from the "Dev Repos".

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Trigger Test Repo workflow
        run: |
          response = $(curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}" --request POST --data '{"ref": "main"}' https://api.github.com/repos/{{organization}}/{{repository}}/actions/workflows/{{workflow-file}}.yml/dispatches)
```

However, the external actions (including the ones suggested by [@VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)) do not trigger any action from the "Dev Repos" to the "Test Repo". The actions do not even show any error in the "Dev Repos". They just appear as successful.

Comment: Have you come to a solution? I also have private repo2 where I want to generate a java WAR archive depending on a JAR archive that is generated from another, repo1. I need to generate and move the JAR from repo1 to repo2 as a result..

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [GitHub Action "Trigger External Workflow"](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/trigger-external-workflow) in order to  triggers a workflow from *another* repository using [`repository_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/pt/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch) event.

```yaml
on: [push, workflow_dispatch]
jobs:
  trigger:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: " Trigger Project Test"
    steps:
    - uses: passeidireto/trigger-external-workflow-action@main
      env:
        PAYLOAD_AUTHOR: ${{ github.author }}
        PAYLOAD_REVISION: "3"
      with:
        repository: my-org/my-repo
        event: doc_update
        github_pat: ${{ secrets.pat_with_access }}
```

> Be sure your `github_pat` has [`workflow` scope](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes) on the target repository (Test).

Then you can use [`action-gh-release`](https://github.com/softprops/action-gh-release) in order to release your Tests packages in a Dev repository.
See "[How to release built artifacts from one to another repo on GitHub?](https://dev.to/oysterd3/how-to-release-built-artifacts-from-one-to-another-repo-on-github-3oo5)" from [Oyster Lee](https://oysterlee.dev/) (also on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6820538/oysterd3))

```
# workflow.yml
# a lot code at the top
# ...
release:
  steps:
    - name: Release
      uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
      with:
        repository: ${{ secrets.owner }}/${{ secrets.repo }}
        token: ${{ secrets.CUSTOM_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: I tried the above approaches, but they didn't work. I have added the details in `Edit I` of the question.

Comment: @SahilKhanna OK. I don't have much more to add, as those were just initial suggestions to test out.